# Have a paragraph and image fit in fixed div

Tags: html, css

I am planing to build several div including a paragraph and a image. The size of image and the paragraph are all different. The div has fixed height, and the image height will be changed to fit the rest of the height after the paragraph. The image should fully display on the div which mean I couldn't do overflow: hidden on the div

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p>This is random information, the height could be differnet depened on the content of the paragraph</p>
  <a href='http://google.ca'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/">
  </a>
</div>
```

However, most of the time image will be overflow, is there any solution I could have image fit into the div by only css?

Comment: are you using any css framework?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust div height by reducing image height! follow this code

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p>This is random information, the height could be differnet depened on the content of the paragraph This is random information, the height could be differnet depened on the content of the paragraph</p>
  <a href='http://google.ca'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/170/nature/">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The content of the paragraph might changed, fixed height image will be overflow if the paragraph is long

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand fully but if you want the image to not break out of it's container, you can simply set the container to overflow:hidden; that way, it will be contained within the container.

Comment: Image should fully display so I couldn't do overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS to the image itself. This will determine the `max-height` and `max-width` of the image based on the parent's dimensions. In this case, `height: 250px;`. The only problem with this is the fact that, if you wanted padding, you have to add the `calc` on the `max-height` for the image (to deduct the padding).

***Note that I have added "Normalize CSS" on this fiddle***

https://jsfiddle.net/7yjhz0dc/2/

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 20px;

  a {
    display: block; // you always want this or inline-block for anchor tags wrapped around images, so the whole image is clickable
  }

  p {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 20px);  // 20px is the parent container's padding
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  <p>This is random information, the height could be differnet depened on the content of the paragraph</p>
  <a href='http://google.ca'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/500/nature/" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
</div>
```

You can see that the image's dimensions (taken from the URL) are in this instance 800px by 500px, yet the image still looks scaled correctly.

If you don't want the `padding` applied to the container, remove from the `.container` and adjust the `max-height` to be `100%;` instead.

Comment: I made the paragraph more longer(just triple the paragraph), then the image will be pushed to out of the div

Comment: Then you're not going to be able to do it w/o restricting the char count of the `p` element's contents. Also, scalable images can only be obtained from the parent's container's height, in this case, a hard set `250px;`, without using Javascript, and without using `overlow: hidden;`